# Using ActiveMQ and GlassFish together

Tags: java, glassfish, activemq-classic

Latest version of both, can not see how to enable ActiveMQ as an endpoint in Glassfish.  Would like to use ActiveMq as the JMS provider in Glassfish, the stuff I found on google does not make sense.  Any advise welcome.

Is it possible to just use the JMS connector and poitn at ActiveMQ - believe not but have I just configured wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: Help me lovely StackOverflow, I'm a .Net developer in a confusing JAVA World with its alien words for things.  Perhaps a JAVA to .Net dictionary would be good :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please look at this tutorial: http://javadude.wordpress.com/2011/07/21/glassfish-v3-1-running-embedded-activemq-for-jms-part-1/

Comment: Ye saw this post very helpful

Answer (score 3):

I've written an article (based on Sven's) that describes how to connect an external activemq broker to glassfish and deploy a Message Driven Bean that consumes messages from ActiveMQ.

You can find it here: http://geertschuring.wordpress.com/2012/04/20/how-to-connect-glassfish-3-to-activemq-5/

Answer (score 1):

1. Deploy activemq-rar-[version].rar as Connector Application to Glassfish
2. You will need some *.jars (http://weblogs.java.net/blog/rampsarathy/archive/2007/03/glassfish_v2_an_1.html) in \domains[domainName]\lib\ext
3. Create Connector Connection Pool with ActiveMQ
4. Create Connector Resource (Factory) with Connector Connection Pool from 2.
5. Create Queues.